# Calculating strings as a formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to evaluate excel cells which contains data like,

"AAA*2"

and then in vba trying to solve them using,

```
    dim AAA
    dim equation
    dim result
    AAA=inputbox("?") 'some numeric value
    equation=sheets("sheet1").range("A1").value 'contains "AAA*2"
    result=application.evaluate("=" & equation)
```

I don't know if something like this possible.If so it's going to make my current project way more simpler.Thanks for any help beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix vba and strings.

Add `equation = replace(equation,"AAA", AAA)`

```
dim AAA
dim equation
dim result
AAA=inputbox("?") 'some numeric value
equation=sheets("sheet1").range("A1").value 'contains "AAA*2"
equation = replace(equation,"AAA", AAA)
result=application.evaluate("=" & equation)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.Simplest thing and i was not able to think.:)This is going to save me a lot of time.

Comment: @canerkorkmaz the assumptions this (and your) code is making *are* going to bite you in the rear end, one day or another.

Comment: @canerkorkmaz I agree with Mat'sMug.  I did the minimum to fix the problem, but his, actually fixes all the problems.

Comment: Actually i did write the above code simplest way possible to ask the question easily.Of course i'm declaring my types in actual project.But in @Mat'sMug 's answer,i learned that i could declare worksheets too.So thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your types, and watch out for implicit assumptions you make with the values involved.

```
Dim userInput As Variant
userInput = InputBox("?") ' could be numeric, could be a null string pointer, could be anything.

If Not IsNumeric(userInput) Then Exit Sub

Dim AAA As Double
AAA = CDbl(userInput)

Dim source As Worksheet
Set source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim sourceEquation As Variant
sourceEquation = source.Range("A1").Value ' could be an error, an empty variant, a date, whatever

If IsError(sourceEquation) Then Exit Sub

Dim equation As String
'the "AAA" in the string is a string literal, doesn't refer to this local AAA variable.
equation = VBA.Strings.Replace(CStr(sourceEquation), "AAA", AAA)

Dim result As Double
result = Application.Evaluate("=" & equation)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I understand what you mean and i will write my codes with that in mind.